# Does CouchDB's group=true prevent rereduce?

Tags: couchdb

CouchDB's map functions emit key/value pairs:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.date, 1);
}
```

Potentially, there could be many key/value pairs with the same key. Setting `group=true` while querying a view groups key/value pairs with the same key into the same reduce:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

Does this mean that with `group=true` (or for any `group_level` > 0), there will be **exactly one reduce per key**?

Or does the grouping only guarantee that all reduces will have homogeneous keys, and that there could still be one or more rereduces?

I am working with a reduce function that is not commutative, but which will not have a large number of records per key. I was hoping that I would be able to set `group=true` and then control the order of operation within a single reduce. If there will be rereduces, then that plan does not make sense.

Comment: "Does this mean that with group=true, there will be exactly one reduce per key?"  I have the same question, please do you have a conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

`group=true` roughly means *"Hey, Couch! Group this map in the way there all keys will be distinct, but don't miss any case of them!"* and actually equals to `group_level=999` (see [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options)).

While you may not guess with proper `group_level` and strip some key items (if key is an array it makes sense), `group` takes care of this for you and rereduce wouldn't be applied.

Also, your reduce function could be replaced with the built-in [`_sum`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions#A_sum) - it's implemented in Erlang and is much faster.

Comment: So you're suggesting that rereduce never happens with any group_level greater than 0?

Comment: It never happens for such group_level, where there is no need to reduce similar unique keys.

Comment: So you're saying rereduce might happen when there is a need to reduce similar keys?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't work out whether this answer boils down to "yes" or "no". Perhaps the second sentence in particular could be rephrased?

Comment: @Kxepal, when group_levelis set to 999 and group is true, rereduce will never happen, yep?

Comment: Yes, unless your key array contains more than 999 elements which unlikely happens.