# rereduce and group=true in CouchDB

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

Actually this question was raised by someone else at [here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338799/does-couchdbs-group-true-prevent-rereduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338799/does-couchdbs-group-true-prevent-rereduce).

But there is no convincing answer.

> group=true is the conceptual equivalent of group_level=exact, so CouchDB runs a reduce per unique key in the map row set.

This is how it is explained in [doc](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping).
It sounds like CouchDB would collect all the values for the same key and only reduce one time per each distinct key.

But in another [article](http://horicky.blogspot.com/2008/10/couchdb-implementation.html), it is said that

> If the query is on the reduce value of each key (group_by_key = true),
>   then CouchDB try to locate the boundary of each key. Since this range
>   is probably not fitting exactly along the B+Tree node, CouchDB need to
>   figure out the edge of both ends to locate the partially matched leave
>   B+Tree node and resend its map result (with that key) to the View
>   Server. This reduce result will then merge with existing rereduce
>   result to compute the final reduce result of this key.

It sounds like rereduce may happen when group=true.

In my project,  there are many documents but there are most 2 values with the same key after grouping for each distinct key.
Will rereduce happen in this case?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Rereduce is always a possibility.

If this is a problem, there is a rereduce parameter in the reduce function, which allows you to detect if this is happening.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#reduce-and-rereduce-functions